# How to select all workers with min begin_date and max end_date in selected order?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

In order "Test" are only two workers:

-Adam Gax
-Andrew Worm

When I write a select sql query:

```
SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE) FROM order_status 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER 
WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';
```

I know what values of the Min. BEGIN_DATE and Max. END_DATE are in Order "TEST":

- MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE): 2019-03-18 06:45:11
- MAX(order_status.END_DATE): 2019-03-22 12:22:33

For worker Adam Gax:

- MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE): 2019-03-18 06:50:35
- MAX(order_status.END_DATE): 2019-03-22 12:22:33

For worker Andrew Worm

- MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE): 2019-03-18 06:45:11
- MAX(order_status.END_DATE): 2019-03-22 11:23:45

I was trying in two ways:

1) With `FULL JOIN` - it means `LEFT JOIN`, `UNION ALL`, `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE), workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME 
FROM order_status 
LEFT JOIN workers ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_status.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER
WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST'
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE), workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME 
FROM order_status
RIGHT JOIN workers ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_status.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER
WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';
```

Then i got the result but it shows only 1 worker:

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
|MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE)|MAX(order_status.END_DATE)|  FNAME | LNAME | 
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-03-18 06:45:11        |   2019-03-22 12:22:33    | Adam   | Gax   |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----+
| 2019-03-18 06:45:11        |   2019-03-22 12:22:33    | Adam   | Gax   |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----+
```

2) I was trying `FULL OUTER JOIN` too - `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `UNION ALL`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`:

```
(SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE), workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME 
FROM order_status 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workers ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_status.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER
WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE), workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME 
FROM order_status
RIGHT OUTER JOIN workers ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_status.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER
WHERE zorders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST');
```

But is the same effect as in the first tried query. I'd achieve the result which should get min.BEGIN_DATE and max.END_DATE:

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
|MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE)|MAX(order_status.END_DATE)|  FNAME | LNAME | 
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-03-18 06:50:35        |   2019-03-22 12:22:33    | Adam   | Gax   |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-03-18 06:45:11        |   2019-03-22 11:23:45    | Andrew | Worm  |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------+-------+
```

It's possible that in order can be more workers but I'd like to concetrate on this case.

Now i have a question: How can i select all workers with min begin_date and max end_date in selected order? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start the joining from the table `workers`.
Then you need to `GROUP BY workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME`:

```
SELECT MIN(os.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(os.END_DATE), w.FNAME, w.LNAME 
FROM workers w 
INNER JOIN order_status os ON w.ID_WORKER = os.ID_WORKER
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.ID_ORDER = os.ID_ORDER 
WHERE o.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST'
GROUP BY w.FNAME, w.LNAME
```

Since you use the `WHERE` clause for the `orders` table, I think there is no need for `LEFT` joins.

Also I used aliases for the tables which is a common good practice.

Comment: Dear... i thought that it should be about any Joins here. Allright never mind. Thank you very much.